# Como esconder div quando clicar em qualquer parte da pagina jquery?

Tags: jquery

Tenho um script que mostra uma div actualmente tenho a mostrar quando clico e esconde quando clico mas quero quando aberta o utilizador quando clicar em qualquer parte da pagina esconda a div alguém pode dar uma ajuda ?

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("body").click(function(){
        $('#opcoes-'+id_agente+'').hide();
    });

    $("body").on('click', '#botao_ver_opcoes', function(e) {
        var id_agente = $(this).data("id-agente");
        $('#opcoes-'+id_agente+'').toggle();
        event.stopPropagation();
    });

    $('#opcoes-'+id_agente+'').hide();
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="opcoes-{{ $agent_tree->user_id }}" style="width: 130px; margin-top: 30px; background-color: white; border: 1px solid #c2c5cd; z-index: 10; position: absolute; display: none; border-top: none;">
    <!--<div data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-add-credito" id="add-credito-btn" data-id-agente="{{ $agent_tree->user_id }}" data-id-line="{{ $agent_tree->credit_line }}" style="text-align: center; line-height: 30px; cursor: pointer;">TRANSFERIR</div>-->
    <div data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-info-agente" id="info-user-btn" data-id-agente="{{ $agent_tree->user_id }}" style="text-align: center; line-height: 30px; cursor: pointer;">INFORMAÇÕES</div>
    <!--<div data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-update-senha" id="change-pwd-btn" data-id-agente="{{ $agent_tree->user_id }}" style="text-align: center; line-height: 30px; cursor: pointer;">SENHA</div>
    <div style="text-align: center; line-height: 30px; cursor: pointer;">MENSAGEM</div>-->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Como esconder div quando clicar em qualquer parte da pagina jquery

Nesse seu trecho de código ao invés de body tem que ser document

```
$("body").click(function(){
    $('#opcoes-'+id_agente+'').hide();
});
```

tem que ser assim

```
 $(document).click(function(){
    $('#opcoes-RESULTid_agente').hide();
 });
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(document).click(function(){
        $('#opcoes-RESULTid_agente').hide();
    });
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="opcoes-RESULTid_agente" style="width: 130px; margin-top: 30px; background-color: white; border: 1px solid #c2c5cd; z-index: 10; position: absolute; border-top: none;">
    <!--<div data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-add-credito" id="add-credito-btn" data-id-agente="{{ $agent_tree->user_id }}" data-id-line="{{ $agent_tree->credit_line }}" style="text-align: center; line-height: 30px; cursor: pointer;">TRANSFERIR</div>-->
    <div data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-info-agente" id="info-user-btn" data-id-agente="{{ $agent_tree->user_id }}" style="text-align: center; line-height: 30px; cursor: pointer;">INFORMAÇÕES</div>
    <!--<div data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-update-senha" id="change-pwd-btn" data-id-agente="{{ $agent_tree->user_id }}" style="text-align: center; line-height: 30px; cursor: pointer;">SENHA</div>
    <div style="text-align: center; line-height: 30px; cursor: pointer;">MENSAGEM</div>-->
</div>
```

> Agora como se referencia o id na função para igualar ao id da div é outra pergunta

Comment: Desde já obrigado pela resposta já testei mas só esconde clicado no botão se clicar em qualquer parte da pagina não fecha mantém aberta a div

Comment: editei a resposta com um exemplo pois faltou seu HTML na pergunta

Comment: Ok coloquei o html agora refaça a resposta se faz favor baseado no que tenho para para depois poder dar a sua resposta como certa

Comment: esse id="opcoes-{{ $agent_tree->user_id }}" da div que tem que colocar no lugar de #login-panel

Comment: O problema e que eu estou a resgasta o user_id astraves de um data atribuito como posso resgastalo quando clico assim fora da pagina senao ele nao me vai saber qual fechar